# Trigger que formate data

Tags: mysql, sql

```
create trigger tr_Fmt_Data before insert
on Tempos
for each row
set new.Mes = date_format(new.Datas, "%M");

insert into Tempos (Datas) values("2017-10-03");
```

Seria possível auxiliarem-me a completar a trigger a cima? Pretendo formatar a data inserida no campo Datas, assumindo o campo Mês apenas o mês da Data.

Comment: Não entendi, consegue me explicar melhor o que deseja?

Comment: Bem, pretendo inserir a data 2017-10-03, no campo Datas e que a trigger tr_Fmt_Data, escreva no campo Mês "Outubro".

Comment: Por favor coloque a estrutura de criação da tabela de data, para que possa escrever a trigger inteira.

Comment: Qual a razão de ter este campo "escrito" ? O valor é redundante e pode ser obtido por sql ou coluna virtual.

Comment: Resolvido, o problema residia na formatação do campo Mes, atribui-lhe varchar                                                                                                create trigger tr_teste before insert
on Services
for each row
set new.Mes = date_format(new.Datas,"%M");